# Is this stored procedure vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-injection

This stored procedure will check for username and password and return `1` if credentials matches else `0`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CheckPermisssions 
    @UserName NVARCHAR(50),
    @Password NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Users WHERE Username=@username and Password=@password)
     RETURN 1
    ELSE
     RETURN 0
END
GO
```

This is just a sample stored procedure. I just want to learn about SQL injection techniques to prevent my code not to be injected.

Assume the inputs are not sanitized in the front end.

I know if I'm using dynamic query in the stored procedure or defined queries in the front end then the SQL injection techniques will work.

Not: Input's will be passed through front end.

**My question in another words**

Can anyone do injection on this query? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5):

SQL injections rarely happen in a stored procedure. For that to happen you would need to create a query dynamically in the procedure.

It's usually the code that is calling the stored procedure that is subject to SQL injection. When you create a query by concatenating values without encoding them correctly, an SQL injection could be used to break out of the value and inject code into the query.

**Example of dangerous code:**

```
string userName = Request.Form("username");
string password = Request.Form("password");

int ok;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr)){

  // parameters are not encoded correctly, so totally open to SQL INJECTION!
  string query = "usp_CheckPermissions '" + userName + "', '" + password + "'";

  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Procedure;
    ok = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  }
}
```

If you log in with the password `';drop table Users;--`, that would be bad...

Answer (score 0):

First rule of thumb to prevent sql injection is:

DO NOT CONCATENATE YOUR QUERY STRINGS WITH USER INPUT.

Use parameters like you did in your example!

Btw. your example is not working because you just declare the
@-variables without assigning any value. should be parameters
for your stored procedure f.e.

Comment: Because it's the first rule of thumb. There are more :P

Comment: Why split one rule to two? Can't a server-sourced data contain a service character as well?

Comment: You definitely have a point here. I just see it from the point of danger to your software. Trusting server sourced data is not as dangerous as trusting user input. But in the end -> don't trust any foreign data. And for the paranoids: don't trust even your own data :D

Comment: There is no use for *trust*. Just *format* your data properly. Always. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has some useful [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on SQL injection. As it explains, there are two scenarios:

- The input is immediately concatenated with other code and executed
- The input is saved directly to a table and retrieved later, concatenated with other code and executed

Since there's no concatenation (dynamic SQL) in this procedure, by itself it's safe. But if some other completely different piece of code concatenates the values later then in theory you could have a problem.

The problem is that in most systems, `';drop table Users;--` is a perfectly valid password, because generally speaking passwords should not be inspected by the system. So someone might input that as a password, hoping that later it will be concatenated and executed.

That all means that you need to use parameters everywhere, all the time, in all your code. And if some data is entirely under the user's control - like passwords - then you need to make sure that you handle them properly even after they've been input.